# Facebook like button for every page (Facebook app)

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'd like to ask, if it's possible to create somehow facebook like button for every product on eshop and connect it to facebook app (so it would be possible to see the graphs and liked pages).

I have this code:

```
 <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?href=www.someurl.com" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; width:311px; height:25px"></iframe>
```

It's basic facebook like button, but it's not connected to any app. So I can't see quite nothing in my app on facebook.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, add the `appId` param. For example:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.plooza.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=80&amp;appId=381429131919273" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Use the like button tool to create the iframe code:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/